# Problemas para alinhar <nav> bar para esquerda

Tags: html, css

Oii pessoal sou **novo** em *CSS*, e estou tendo algumas dificuldades para formatar algumas coisas recentemente.

Eu assisti uma aula para fazer essa navbar do codigo abaixo e encaixei um parallax que eu tinha feito ontem ja nessa navbar para eu conseguir finalmente finalizar o site.

Acontece que quando inseri os codigos do parallax, o menu se desconfigurou. 
Eu tirei a margin de algumas classes no css e ele voltou para o alinhamento, mas nao aonde eu quero.

Eu quero colocar os itens da minha "li" alinhados na esquerda junto com a img src da "logo".

Alguem consegue me ajudar?
Vou por os codigos aqui e uma imagem de como está, para voces entenderem a minha idéia.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color:#F06;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 10%;
  background: #24252a;
  border-radius:10px;
}

.logo {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin:0;
}

.nav__links {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.nav__links a,
.cta,
.overlay__content a {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #edf0f1;
  text-decoration: none;
  
}

.nav__links li {
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

.nav__links li a {
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.nav__links li a:hover {
  color: #0088a9;
}

.cta {
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 9px 25px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 136, 169, 1);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.cta:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 136, 169, 0.8);
}


.container{
 position: relative;
    margin: 100px auto 0;
 max-width: 960px;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #000, #262626);
 font-size: 24px; 
 padding: 25px; 
 
}

.parallax {
 background:url(_images/background.jpg) no-repeat center;
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 height: 350px;
 
}

.container::before,
.container::after
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left: -2px;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg,#fb0094,#0000ff, #00ff00, #ffff00, #ff0000, #fb0094,#0000ff, #00ff00, #ffff00, #ff0000);
    background-size: 400%;
    width: calc(100% + 4px);
    height: calc(100% + 4px);
    z-index: -1;
    animation: animate 20s linear infinite;
}

.shadow::after
{
    filter: blur(20px);
}

@keyframes animate
{
    0%
    {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    50%
    {
        background-position: 300% 0;
    }
    100%
    {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Navbar</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
            <img class="logo" src="_images/logo.png" alt="logo">
            <nav>
                <ul class="nav__links">
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <a class="cta" href="#">Contact</a>
        </header>
        </div>
        
        <div class="container">
 
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
<div class="parallax">
</div>

<div id="paral2"> 
<p><strong>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</strong></p>

</div>



</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu `header` vc colocou `justify-content: flex-end;` mas na verdade deveria ser `justify-content: flex-start;`, usando `flex-star` os itens ficaram alinhados a esquerda

```
header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 30px 10%;
    background: #24252a;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado mestre!!!

Comment: Posso aproveitar e perguntar como eu faria um espaçamento entre os itens da lista? pra ficar melhor nesse header

Comment: @MrBloodCreek vlw, coloca um margin-right nos itens do menu que deve resolver